# Is there any known exploit that enables computer infection through media files (image, videos and audio)?

Tags: malware

or: Is an AVI/MP3/JPG file a potential malware?

Comment: the list of flash vulnerabilities is endless.

Comment: I hate this type of question as I always wonder if I am helping a potential malware author.

Comment: @Matt IMHO 1st Malware authors don't depend on public forums 2nd public forums help common users to protect themselves against attacks and 3rd the proportion of victims helped are far greater than hackers. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/would-you-teach-black-hat-techniques-in-public-forums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.internetnews.com/security/article.php/3412161 is an example of JPEG Exploits

Answer (score 1):

If this helps, I've once had an MP3 force open a malicious website in my browser mid-way through a song...

Comment: That was almost certainly a WMA file mis-identified with a .mp3 extension.

Comment: @bobince: Could have had a "download license from this malware site" URL in it, fwiw. DRM FTL.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is. Malware can be disguised as just about anything. Scan the file for viruses and don't trust files from someone you don't know.

Comment: I suggest you don't trust the files from someone you do know. If they're infected they certainly don't know it. Scan everything.